# Boost ASIO async_accept compilation fails

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, bind, boost-asio

Man... thought using ASIO in Boost was going to be easy and intuitive. :P

I am starting to get it finally but I am having some trouble. Here's a snippet.
I am having several compiler errors on the async_accept line. What am I doing wrong? :P

I've based my code off of this page:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html

Errors:

> Error 1   error C2780: 'void
>   boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor::async_accept(boost::asio::basic_socket
>   &,boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint
>   &,AcceptHandler)' : expects 3
>   arguments - 2
>   provided  e:\schoolcode\senior
>   project\cplusplusport\cplusplusport\alexsocket.cpp    36
>
> Error 2   error C2784: 'void
>   boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor::async_accept(boost::asio::basic_socket
>   &,AcceptHandler)' : could not deduce
>   template argument for
>   'boost::asio::basic_socket
>   &' from 'boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket
>   *'    e:\schoolcode\senior project\cplusplusport\cplusplusport\alexsocket.cpp 36

```
bool TestSocket::StartListening(int port)
{
    bool didStart = false;

    if (!this->listening)
    {
        //try to listen
        acceptor = new tcp::acceptor(this->myService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
        didStart = true; //probably change?
        tcp::socket* tempNewSocket = new tcp::socket(this->myService);
        acceptor->async_accept(tempNewSocket, boost::bind(&TestSocket::NewConnection, this, tempNewSocket, boost::asio::placeholders::error) );
    }
    else //already started!
        return false;

    this->listening = didStart;
    return didStart;
}

void TestSocket::NewConnection(tcp::socket* s, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{

}
```

Comment: Give us more info. You bind to `AlexSocket::NewConnection` with `this` as the first arg - but as far as I can see, `this` is-not-a `AlexSocket` - is it? And is the NewConnection method virtual?

Comment: ugh. I was trying to get rid of my silly "MyName" prefix I add to all my classes when I'm writing learning code. :P

Comment: I think the first argument must be *tempNewSocket. Please add the errors you get to your question. Without that, we can just guess what errors you have.

Comment: Errors added. Apologies for the oversight. :)

Comment: @bobber205 I suggest you use smart pointers.  Avoid calling new directly as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

async_accept expects a reference to the socket, not a pointer, so try

```
acceptor->async_accept(*tempNewSocket, ...
```